# How to make embeded video on android´s webview open on fullscreen below API 11?

Tags: android, webview, youtube

So, my overall situation is as follows: I have to get some HTML from a wordpress database and render it on a webview.

So I cant work with youtube API , I must render this HTML, ill have embeded videos on it and I need them to pop up on fullscreen. This solution [Videos not playing in fullscreen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108536/videos-not-playing-in-fullscreen-mode) wont work on API 10.

Is there anyway to make the embeded videos play on fullscreen below API 11?

Answer (score 2):

You can create Frame layout above your WebView and attach to it VideoView. This way you can manage size, add custom MediaControls but there are a lot of work and you will faced with many problems.

**Edit:** You can capture event by:

- if you can handle html, you can add JS method, that calls your application method throught the JS bridge. As example you put an image with `onclick` event. Click by this image calls `JsVideFrameCallbackImpl.playVideo('videoUrl')` in your app (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/09/using-webviews.html):

  ```
  <img src="img/video_1.jpg" width="494px" height="340px" onclick="javascript: JsVideFrameCallbackImpl.playVideo('videoUrl')">
  ```

and attach `addJavascriptInterface` in your activity to webview:

```
wv.addJavascriptInterface(new JsVideFrameCallbackImpl(), "JsVideFrameCallbackImpl");

//....

private final class JsVideFrameCallbackImpl {
    private final static String LOG_TAG = "JsVideFrameCallbackImpl";

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void playVideo(final String videoUri) {
                    // call VideoPlayer activity as example
        startActivity(new Intent(context, VideoPlayer.class));
    }
}
```

- or you can get the coords of any html element on the page via the same js-bridge and place `VideoView` on `FrameLayout` (Do not forget enable js in webview `wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); before using javascript in webview`):

  ```
   wv.loadUrl("javascript: jsInitMedia()"); // call js method jsInitMedia
  ```

jsInitMedia in the html (or you can apply this code directly in WebView as: `wv.loadUrl("javascript: var el = document.getElemen...")`:

```
    function jsInitMedia() {
        var el = document.getElementById(dataArray[i]); var coords = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        // get top, left coords, width and height with coords.width, el.offsetTop and so on. Send them back as string (i use json format)
        JsVideFrameCallbackImpl.init(jsonDataWithCoordsAsString);
    }
```

and in your java code in `JsVideFrameCallbackImpl` :

```
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void init(final String json) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Init:" + json);
        // parse json and extract left, top, width and height
                    // now you can place any View with corresponding coords on your frame
                    //as well you can easy handle all click events  
    }
```

Comment: How can I capture the event of the video playing from a webview and play it on the VideoView, then?

Comment: I'm going to add answer to your question in my answer, ok?

Comment: Ill just set the minimum API to 11. Your solution is not pratical, since Im not writing the code that will output the HMTL. Not to mention that that I would have to find a way to get the image for the video and the image by itself wouldnt be intuitive enough to indicate an embedded video.

Comment: >  Im not writing the code that will output the HMTL. It's not nessesary, only that you need - find element by id or class name on the html page. And that all. The other you execute from the app code.

Comment: by the way it's mine solution, worked for my situation but you could look further

Comment: Alright, so I have an iframe that embeds a youtube video. I can not make it call a javascript call, how can I know when and identify it when it starts to play a video?

Comment: Look, video is started by user click, right? you just attach to your view onClickListener and now you can handle all user events